# Why is the browser making multiple requests to the page URL?

Tags: http, firefox, http-headers, firefox-developer-tools, http-accept-encoding

Here is a [page](https://dwbi.org/pages/35/dimensional-modeling-approach-for-various-slowly-changing-dimensions) from my website.

When browsers, such as Firefox and Safari load this page, they are requesting the same document multiple times. See the screenshot from developer tool below.

[image]

For the 3 lines pointed above, browser requests and server responses are exactly same except `Accept` headers are slightly different.

For the **1st** request, request header is:

```
Host: dwbi.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://dwbi.org/categories/11/dimensional-model
Cookie: xxxxx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And for the **2nd** and **3rd**, request header is exactly same (but different from the **1st** - see `Accept`):

```
Host: dwbi.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://dwbi.org/pages/35/dimensional-modeling-approach-for-various-slowly-changing-dimensions
Cookie: xxxxx
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

These multiple requests are getting registered as 3 different visits in backend. Why browsers are sending these multiple requests and how do I prevent them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because this line in your website:

`<img id="modal-image" class="max-w-full w-full1" src="#" style="user-select: auto;">`

The source is point to this page, but the request is asking for image type of data.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @AppleJam below, the issue occurred due to `src="#"` attribute in `img` tag.

As a solution to this problem, I am now populating `src` attribute with a blank GIF image as below.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" />
```